# How to normalize slope of historical financial data?

Tags: regression, normalization, finance

Im trying to find a method to normalize the slope value for the historical net profits of many companies. But the problem arises when certain companies are clocking profits in thousands, and some in millions. The slope is higher for the latter. But there are chances where the growth of a lower slope company is higher than that of company with a higher slope. For example, I have the following 2 hypothetical companies and their net profits:

[image]

Is there a method I can apply so that the slope is normalized and allow me to use it comparitively? After doing some search, I found a few methods:

Slope / Latest Value

Slope / Average Average

Slope / Range Average

So in my case, it would be dividing the slope with either the latest year net profits, the average of the historical net profits, or the range(max - min) of the net profits. The problem is, Im not able to identify which is a better approach. The values I get for these are as follows:

[image]

PS: Im not opting to use absolute returns or CAGR because there are times when negative values come up, and it misleads my interpretation.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You say that sometimes the growth can be higher for smaller companies than large? Higher in what sense, that the small company grew by $50\%$ and the large by $10\%$, even though the dollar/euro/whatever amount for the large company is larger?

Comment: Yes. I meant in terms of the growth as you said, and not just in currency terms.

Comment: If profits were always positive, then taking logarithms before calculating the slope would make some kind of sense and would give something related to the trend growth rate.  But, as you say, they are not always positive